# PHP_SELF does not accept the string after character "<"

Tags: php

I am learning PHP from http://www.w3schools.com. In the section http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp, it mentions the security risk of PHP_SELF, and give an example `http://www.example.com/test_form.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E`.

However, when I try this example in my test environment (XAMPP on Mac OS X Yosemite), I cannot see the popped script box. Then, I try to print/echo the content of PHP_SELF, it is strange to see that the string after "<" is ignored.

My testing script is as following:

```
<?php
    echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], "<br>";
?>
```

When I enter `localhost/20160108.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E` in Safari/Chorme address bar, I get:

> /20160108.php/">

When I enter `localhost/20160108.php/%22%3Escript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E`, I get:

> /20160108.php/">script>alert('hacked')

Seems that PHP_SELF does not accept sub-strings following `%3C` (i.e. "<").

Could anyone help me understand and solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please format your code properly. The new question window shows how it looks and you can clearly see it's broken. It also tells how to format it, so please take a note and fix it.

Comment: if you are testing in chrome, try setting `header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");`. this header is common in browser(?), which will detect potential XSS attack

Comment: Thanks for your help, Chris, Sami and Andrew. After check the html code, I see it javascript was blocked by XSS Auditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I enter
>   localhost/20160108.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E
>   in Safari/Chorme address bar, I get:

```
/20160108.php/">
```

> When I enter
>   localhost/20160108.php/%22%3Escript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E, I
>   get:

```
/20160108.php/">script>alert('hacked')
```

> Seems that PHP_SELF does not accept sub-strings following %3C (i.e.
>   "<").

PHP_SELF does accept it. Note in your second url

```
localhost/20160108.php/%22%3Escript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E
```

does not have `%3C("<")` after `%3E(">")`

and i think you are expecting `/20160108.php/"><script>alert('hacked')</script>` , so you might try this url

```
localhost/20160108.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E
```

I did a simple test and PHP_SELF does accept it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">

</form>
<?php 
    echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

browsing the file with `localhost/20160108.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E` will cause an alert in mozilla firefox but not in google chrome.

Comment: Thanks, Jameshwart. After checked the html code, I see the message "The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://localhost/20160108.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header. ".

Comment: seems it helps you. can you accept it as the correct answer by clicking the check icon?

Answer (score 0):

A "page" is written in HTML, so `<` means "start a tag".  You have to represent characters with special meaning in HTML using [entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).  The [htmlspecialchars](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp) function should do what you want:

```
<?php
    echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]), "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Steve. The javascript code is blocked by the XSS auditor.